# Authentication failed as remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: .net, exchange-server, imap, .net-framework-version, sslstream

I am trying to connect to an Exchange server using IMAP from my .NET 4.0 application. Below is the code I have problem with:

```
var host = "mail.mydomain.com";
var port = 993;
var tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
var stream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, (sender, cert, chain, e) => true, null);
stream.AuthenticateAsClient(host); // => IOException here
```

I get `Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream` on the last line.
I have already tried to use the below workarounds with no luck:

- ```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  ```
- Changed target framework to .NET 4.5 and tried:

  ```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
  ```
- Added `SchUseStrongCrypto` registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319`and rebooted.

However, if I change target framework of my program to .NET 2.0, same code works with no problem. 
My program is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm having the same issues. I have made the changes described above. Working on localhost but error on Windows Server 2012R2, IIS 8.5

Comment: @ozimax06 Instead of built-in libraries, I used  [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and it worked with no problem